# Are there any USB microphones under $10 that will record talking-volume sound 2-3 meters away?

Tags: usb, microphones

I have several small USB microphones, which work just fine as long as my mouth is within a few inches of the mic's input. However, I am looking for a small and cheap microphone (under $10 from somewhere like Amazon) that doesn't require such close proximity.

Are there any such cheap USB microphones that can record normal volume speaking that takes place 2-3 meters away from the mic?

Comment: 2 to 3 meters away?  Not for under $50 are you going to find one that gives you any quality worth the trouble of making the recording in the first place.  We use the [Blue Snowball](https://goo.gl/DOsxKW) in the center of 6 meter rectangular table and it picks up everyone's voice clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Like Digital Boffin said, you're not going to be able to get something worthwhile under $10. I also use a Blue Snowball for recordings and it works very well. If you poke around on ebay, you may be able to find a used Blue Snowball. I was able to find one [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Blue-Snowball-Microphone-USB-Mic-Only-/192000981375?hash=item2cb426797f:g:y6UAAOSwh2xX~Vjx) on ebay for $25. If you want to get something that's new, you're going to have pay at least $50 for something decent like the [Snowball Ice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014PYGTUQ). Or about $70 for the ["real" Snowball](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000EOPQ7E). n.b. the snowball is a *USB mic.*

**In conclusion:**

- A mic under $10 probably isn't worth it (esp. for the conditions you described)
- You're probably going to  need to spend at least $50 or more for something decent like the Snowball or Snowball  Ice.
- If $50 is too far out of your price range, you could try poking around on ebay for a used Snowball or something similar (I was able to find one for about $25 w/o shipping, which shouldn't be to expensive)

Answer (score 1):

In case your radio won't take a USB input... Here are a couple 3.5mm options:

- Poking around Amazon I found the "[Floureon BM-800 Condenser Sound Studio Recording Broadcasting Microphone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00Q4RGQHY)" for **$30** it's the best seller so it's probably not too bad.
- "[Tonor 3.5mm Studio Professional Microphone Mic with Stand For Audio Sound Recording Skype Desktop PC Laptop Notebook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01297CD6U)" for **$10.99**, also on amazon.com.

But like I mentioned earlier, you generally get what you pay for... ***Higher price generally = Higher quality, more reliability.*** Caveat emptor.